# "Can I meet you at 6?" is wrong?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

When I make an appointment with my hair stylist, can I say "Can I meet you at 6?" ?

Answer (score 2):

A more appropriate expression is

> Can I make an appointment for 6 (am/pm)?

Or,

> Is 6 (am/pm) available?

Or,

> I'd like to make an appointment for 6 (am/pm). Is that time available?

"Can I meet you at 6?" is used more for casual situations, like when you're meeting a friend for lunch or coffee.

Comment: *Can I meet you at 6?* would be at least *slightly* "odd" in most "casual situations" (where ***Shall we** meet at 6?* would be most "natural", and ***Can** we meet at 6?* would cover any contextual requirement for "servility").

Comment: **Shall** sounds distinctly BrE to my AmE ears and would be unusual on this side of the Atlantic.  AmE speakers in a casual situation would be more likely to say, "**Should** I meet you at 6?"

Answer (score 1):

In general, we arrange to "meet" someone in a public place. If you are making an appointment to go to the hair stylists's salon, you might say "shall I come at six?"